# How to convert date range input into string in R Shiny?

Tags: r, string, date, shiny, reactive-programming

I have a shiny app where I want to make a title that says "Q1" when the user selects Jan 1 and Q2 if the user selects Apr 1, etc., but for some reason, I cannot convert the date range input into a character.

For instance, I know that this code works on regular strings:

```
 date <- "2020-10-01"
 
library(stringr)
libary(dplyr)
  date <- date %>%
   str_remove("^..") %>%
   str_replace_all("-", "/")
 
 starting <- if(str_detect(date, "../01/01")) {
   print("Q1")
 } else if(str_detect(date, "../04/01")){
   print("Q2")
 } else if(str_detect(date, "../07/01")){
   print("Q3")
 } else if(str_detect(date, "../10/01")){
   print("Q4")
 } else{
   paste0(str_extract(date, ".....$"), "/", str_extract(date, "^.."))
 }
 #Correctly says Q4
 starting
```

But, when I try to put it in a shiny app, I get various errors, like:

```
Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

How do I get this app to use the above code to change the rendered text in the message output below? Note: for simplicity, I'm only working with the first input in the date filter, but if for some reason, the second would differ please let me know what I need to do.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ui <- fluidRow(
    column(12,
           div(id = "inputs",
               dateRangeInput(
                   inputId = "date_filter",
                   label = "Filter by Date",
                   start = "2020-01-01",
                   end = (today() + 90),
                   min = "2021-01-01",
                   max = NULL,
                   format = "yyyy-m-d",
                   startview = "month",
                   weekstart = 0,
                   language = "en",
                   separator = " to ",
                   width = NULL,
                   autoclose = TRUE
               )),
        textOutput("message")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    start_date <- reactive({input$datefilter[1]
        })
    
    start_date <- reactive({start_date %>%
        str_remove("^..") %>%
        str_replace_all("-", "/")
    })
    
    starting <- reactive({
        if(str_detect(start_date, "..../01/01")) {
            print("Q1")
        } else if(str_detect(start_date, "..../04/01")){
            print("Q2")
        } else if(str_detect(start_date, "..../07/01")){
            print("Q3")
        } else if(str_detect(start_date, "..../10/01")){
            print("Q4")
        } else{
            paste0(str_extract(start_date, ".....$"), "/", str_extract(start_date, "^.."))
        }
        })
    
    
    output$message <- renderText({
        starting
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Edit:

I also tried to put everything in one reactive, but now I get an agrument is of length zero:

```
    output$message <- renderText({
        
        start_date <- input$datefilter[1]
        
        start_date <- start_date %>%
                str_remove("^..") %>%
                str_replace_all("-", "/")
        
        starting <- 
            if(str_detect(start_date, "..../01/01")) {
                print("Q1")
            } else if(str_detect(start_date, "..../04/01")){
                print("Q2")
            } else if(str_detect(start_date, "..../07/01")){
                print("Q3")
            } else if(str_detect(start_date, "..../10/01")){
                print("Q4")
            } else{
                paste0(str_extract(start_date, ".....$"), "/", str_extract(start_date, "^.."))
            }
    })
```

Comment: It is not clear why you want to do this with `if/else if`..  Try with `format(zoo::as.yearqtr(as.Date(date)), 'Q%q')#
[1] "Q4"`

Comment: @akrun, thanks for sharing the function, I'll check it out. The if/else isn't the issue though; Shiny isn't letting me put the daterange input into a string to do either transformation.

Comment: The below solution works for me.  it prints the quarter value when the user changes the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simplified with `as.yearqtr` from `zoo` to convert to `yearqtr` and then use `format` to extract only the quarter

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  
  output$message <- renderText({
    
    format(zoo::as.yearqtr(input$date_filter[1]), 'Q%q')
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

---

Regarding the OP's code, there are couple of issues

1. `datefilter` instead of `date_filter`
2. When we call the output from a reactive use `()`.  In the below, code, it is removed to a single reactive
3. After we get the substring with `str_remove`, using `....` as pattern will not match.  It should be `..`

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
 
  
  output$message <- renderText({
    
   req(input$date_filter[1])
    tmp <- as.character(input$date_filter[1]) %>%
      str_remove("^..") %>%
      str_replace_all("-", "/")
    
     if(str_detect(tmp, "../01/01")) {
       "Q1"
     } else if(str_detect(tmp, "../04/01")){
       "Q2"
     } else if(str_detect(tmp, "../07/01")){
       "Q3"
     } else if(str_detect(tmp, "../10/01")){
       "Q4"
     } else{
       paste0(str_extract(tmp, ".....$"), "/", str_extract(tmp, "^.."))
     }
     
  })
  
}
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the code, but unfortunately, I need to use the nested if/else statements because it should only say Q1 if the date starts on exactly Jan 1, etc. Only if the start date doesn't fall on one of those 4 days, then it has to show it's actual day in the specific format I have specified. I tried modifying your code within the if/else statements, but the date-range doesn't contain leading 0s, so it never matches. I also need this information to be a string for a powerpoint table I export, so it's not just to render it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @J.Sabree your code showed in the post, gives me `starting#
[1] "10/01 '20"` outside the shiiny.  Is that your expected

Comment: good catch. I fixed the code now. It should say Q4 if starts on 10/1, etc. and if it's not on one of the 4 quarter starts, (like 11/01/2020), it should say 11/01/20.

Comment: @J.Sabree you need `start_date()`

Comment: at what part? I tried making every part reactive when I was troubleshooting but kept it failing

Comment: why you are creating multiple reactive statements.  Could have been in a single one

Comment: I just tried making them all as one reactive, but it still fails, albeit with a different error.

Comment: @J.Sabree i understand the issue. there are multiple issues - `datefilter` is not `date_filter` and you need to use `()` while invoking

Comment: @J.Sabree please check the updat

Comment: wow, I feel silly that I missed the hypen. Your solution worked but one callout: in the final, I didn't have to use () when I passed it all through renderText. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Sabree I was just checking it in a single reactive to debug the issue